# error +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Savedata''

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

this is my delegate.m

```
#import "TestSaveDataAppDelegate.h"

#import "TestSaveDataViewController.h"

@implementation TestSaveDataAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

This is my NSManagedObjectContext

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

This is my NSManagedObjectModel

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }    
    __managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

This is my NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SaveData.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

In my TestSaveDataViewController.h i import my Savedata.h exactly name like inside my Model.xcdatamodeld with entity name is Savedata, attribute inside here is saveslot1 with string type.

in my TestSaveDataViewController.m

@synthesize managedObjectContext;

i have a button like this

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
    // save text in textfield
    Savedata *savedata = (Savedata *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Savedata" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [savedata setSaveslot1:label1.text];    
    NSError *error;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // This is a serious error saying the record could not be saved.
        // Advise the user to restart the application
    }
}
```

When the button is push, the text in the textfield will save and show it label1.text
but i got this error.

```
+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'Savedata''
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

i already solve my problem. i forgot to delegate it. now it works.